# Fail the regex match at the end of the string in Go

Tags: regex, go, regex-greedy

I'm trying to test a string against this pattern: "At least one square bracket pair, wrapping 2 digits, followed by at lease one  character". For example, `[11][22][33]dd` should match while `[11][22][33]` shouldn't.

I've tried this regex: `(\[\d{2}])+.+`. However, when it is tested against with `[11][22][33]`, which should have failed, it still passes that test. The first `+` quantifier only matches two groups `[11]` and `[22]`, while the rest part `[33]` is matched by `.+`.

I thought the "greedy" behaviour of the `+` quantifier would exhaust all the matching segments of the group it modifies; however it seems that the regex engine would place the "exhaust all matching possibilities" principle above the "greedy quantifier" rule, not the way I'd expected.

How should I achieve my goal?

(This question is actually language-agnostic, though tagged with "golang" which is the language I'm currently using.)

Comment: Jutst a negated `[`, `(?:\[\d{2}])+[^[]`, should do thew job. Also, regex is not language-agnostic.

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/TYzR6k_PPN5

Comment: @mkopriva This one won't match if the 'any character' part is not a `\w` character, e.g. `[11][22][33]---dd` won't match

Comment: The question is, do you want to match `[11][22][33][some text here`?

Comment: The problem here is caused by backtracking, once the pattern does not match, the quantified pattern lets the engine backtrack to find another way to match the string, and once the path succeeds, the match is returned. Possessive quantifiers and capturing groups inside lookaheads with backreference later won't work in Go regex. So, the only way to solve this is to write a more precise pattern, but you need to precise the rules.

Comment: Well, try `(?:\[\d{2}])+(?:\[(?:\D|\d\D|\d{2}[^]])|[^\[]|\[(?:\d?|\d{3,})])`, see https://regex101.com/r/mlPKMx/2

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/nvMY2kSB4J2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your suggestion, and [this issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/7713) seems to suggest that support of possessive quantifiers is currently unplanned. For now I'd simply switch the final quantifier to `*` and do an extra check on whether the final part is empty.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Similar to @mkopriva's, I'm using `(\[\d{2}])+(.*)` and checking whether the 2nd match group is empty

Comment: @GarlicXu Thtat might be the best approach here unless all the strings you have match `\[\d{2}]` pattern.

Comment: I think you should precise the question: you want to return `true` if there is a `\[\d{2}]` pattern match NOT at the end of the string. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?:\[\d{2}])+(.*)`)
match := re.FindStringSubmatch(s)
if len(match) > 1 {
    return match[1] != ""
}
return false
```

The `(?:\[\d{2}])+(.*)` pattern matches 1+ occurrences of `[`, 2 digits, `]` and then captures any 0 or more chars other than line break chars into Group 1. Then, if the match was found (`if len(match) > 1`), `true` should be returned if the Group 1 value is not empty (`match[1] != ""`), otherwise, `false` is returned.

See [Go demo](https://play.golang.com/p/Z-_rpEKE8qr):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    strs := []string{
        "[11][22][33]",
        "___[11][22][33]",
        "[11][22][33]____",
        "[11][22]____[33]",
    }
    for _, str := range strs {
        fmt.Printf("%q - %t\n", str, match(str))
    }
}

var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(?:\[\d{2}])+(.*)`)

func match(s string) bool {
    match := re.FindStringSubmatch(s)
    if len(match) > 1 {
        return match[1] != ""
    }
    return false
}
```

Output:

```
"[11][22][33]" - false
"___[11][22][33]" - false
"[11][22][33]____" - true
"[11][22]____[33]" - true
```

Answer (score 0):

the regular expression you need to use is i presume goes like that:

```
(\[[0-9]{2}\]){1,}[a-z]{1,}
```